# Plot Vertex shape in iGraph in R

Tags: r, igraph

#### Hi people,

I have a question that should be simple. I am new using iGraph and I am trying to plot by tklplot. The graph has the following characteristics:

`Vertices:  856   Edges:  675   Directed:  TRUE`

I just want to shape to different ethnic groups that are of course attributes `V(g)$ethnic` of the vertices,  in  the  graph.
I  had  a  problem  with    `square`,  but  it  did  have  a  bug.
In  the  lines  downwards  I  just  become  circle  shaped  vertices  .   My  idea  is  to  differentiate  the  vertices  with  the  attribute `V(g)$ethnic` ,  if  I  recall  it,  there  is no  problem  ,  but  the  plot  output  is  not  true  ,  and  no  major  problem  is  reported  by  R

as   follows

```
  V(g)$color <- "green"
  E(g)$color <- "black"
  V(g)$nodesize=degree(g)*0.5
  V(g)[V(g)$ethnic=="Mestizo"]$shape <- "rectangle"
  V(g)[V(g)$ethnic=="Saraguro"]$shape <- "circle"
  tkplot(g, layout=layout.kamada.kawai, edge.color=E(g)$color, 
         edge.arrow.size=0.3, vertex.label.dist=0.3, vertex.color=V(g)$color, 
         vertex.size=V(g)$nodesize, vertex.shape=V(g)$shape)
```

regards
Vladimir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [igraph.vertex.shapes function documentation](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc-0.5.2/R/igraph.vertex.shapes.html), shapes are not supported in `tkplot` but only in `plot.igraph`:

> Note that the current vertex shape implementation is experimental  and
>   it might change in the future. Currently vertex shapes are implemented
>   only for plot.igraph.

Answer (score -1):

What exactly is not plotting correctly? The indices for iGraph are offset by one. Try this and see if it makes a difference:

```
wc1 <- which(V(g)$ethnic=="Mestizo") - 1
wc2 <- which(V(g)$ethnic=="Saraguro") - 1
V(g)$shape[wc1] <- "rectangle"
V(g)$shape[wc2] <- "circle"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers,
 the above formulation did not work in neither in `tkplot` nor in `plot.igraph`: the following Warnmeldung was reported: `In graph[[9]][[3]][[name]][index + 1] <- value : Anzahl der zu ersetzenden Elemente ist kein Vielfaches der Ersetzungslänge` or with  `plot.igraph` ,  `Fehler in igraph.check.shapes(params("vertex", "shape")) : Bad vertex shape(s): NA.`  :   it means that somehow there is a problem with the shapes or there is something no recognizable.